# gdb changing the value of sigint as caught by sigwait in a handler thread?

Tags: gdb, pthreads, signals

I have a multithreaded (pthreads) application where I have hooked `SIGINT` to allow me to interrupt the program. I set up a signal hander thread like so:

```
    /*** startup code ***/
// Prep signal-related stuff:
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
assert(0 == pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL));

// Spawn signal handling thread
pthread_t sig_pthread;
pthread_create(&sig_pthread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
```

The signal handler thread is here:

```
static void* sig_thread(void *arg) {
    sigset_t *set = (sigset_t *) arg;
    int s, sig;

#ifndef __APPLE__
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "signal hander", 0, 0, 0);
#endif

    for (;;) {
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0) {
            ERR(E_UNKNOWN, "sigwait failed?\n");
            /* ERR is macro -> exit(E_UNKNOWN) */
        }

        if (sig == SIGINT) {
            ...
        } else {
            ERR(E_UNKNOWN, "caught unknown signal %d\n", sig);
            /* ERR is macro -> exit(E_UNKNOWN) */
        }
    }
}
```

When running normally, the code works as expected. However, if I run the program under gdb, I get:

`--- E: caught unknown signal 4611`

Does anyone have any insight on the (decimal) value 4611 (0x1203, 01103)? It was not anything obvious in `signal.h`. Does anyone know what gdb is doing to cause this to happen and how I can fix / prevent it?

Comment: The code that contains `  /*** startup code ***/` , does this thread/function/etc. still exist as the sig_thread() thread is running - just to make sure the `set` variable you hand over to sig_thread() still exists and isn't garbage ?

Comment: Yes, it lives for the life of the process.

Comment: I think it probably isn't anything gdb is doing per se; but rather a kernel and/or libc problem.  If I were investigating this I might try watching the kernel behavior here using systemtap.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `4611` to be garbage, as you do not initialise `sig` prior to calling `sigwait()`.

From the sources you show, it seems like you do not skip the test of `sig` in case of an error (`s != 0`).

You might like to mod your code like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <signal.h>
...

#define E_UNKNOWN "E"
#define ERR(ec, fmt, ...) (fprintf(stderr, "--- %s: " fmt, (ec), __VA_ARGS__))

...

  for (;;) {
    int sig = 0;
    int s = sigwait(set, &sig);

    if (s != 0) {
        ERR(E_UNKNOWN, "sigwait() failed with %d.\n", s);
    }
    else {
      if (sig == SIGINT) {
          ...
      } else {
        ERR(E_UNKNOWN, "Caught unhandled signal %d.\n", sig);
      }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: It should never get there however. `ERR` is a macro that expands to `exit()` with some pretty-printing. If `s != 0` the code will die before reaching the unhandled signal line. I've edited the question to make this slightly clearer.

Comment: @Pat: I see. However, you do yourself a favour initialising `sig` prior to calling `sigwait()`, because you will then see whether `sigwat()` set the `4611` or not.